# Lerna bootstrap doesn't install symlink

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, lerna

I have a project and updated from node v14 (npm 6) to node LTS (npm 8.3)

Lerna bootstrap doesn't install my dependencies as symlink.

Structure:

```
.X
├── lerna.json
├── package.json (My node_modules contains A and B packages)
├── packages
│   ├── A
│   │   └── package.json (install two as symlink (taking from root node_modules)- but 
│   │                     it's not working)
│   └── B
│       └── package.json
.Y
├── lerna.json
├── package.json (My node_modules contains A and B packages)
├── packages
│   ├── C
│   │   └── package.json (it should installs A and B as symlink)
│   │
│   └── D
│       └── package.json (it should installs A as symlink)
```

When I use node v14, lerna bootstrap install correctly but when I use v16 it's not..